# Need assistance with PHP $_FILE File Upload Script

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am creating an upload script with PHP and HTML that could have any number of file uploads. I loop through and echo out any number of file uploads and name each one "fileField1", "fileField2" and so on using a loop.

Now I want to retrieve the name of the file in that field. Can I use a variable in another loop like this?

```
  $fileField = 'fileField'.$i;

    $fileName = $_FILES[$fileField]['name']; // Name of file
```

This is contained within the loop, will this work?

I believe I am experiencing an error...

Variable $i is increased by one each time ($i++)

**EDIT**

Notice the comment that I never reach...

Here is the whole loop:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $numberOfFields) {
$fileField = 'fileField'.$i;
$titleId = 'title'.$i;
$genreId = 'genre'.$i;

    $fileName = $_FILES[$fileField]['name']; // Name of file 

    if($fileName !=""){
        $randNum = rand(1000000000,9999999999); //Generate random number

        $newFileName = $fileName."-".$randNum; //Rename file

            if (file_exists($baseUrl."images/".$newFileName)){
            echo $newFileName." already exists. ";
            }else{      
                if(isset($_POST[$titleId]) && !empty($_POST[$titleId])){
                    // Assign url, title, genre
                    $url = 'images/'.$newFileName;          
                    $title = $_POST[$titleId];          
                    $genre = $_POST[$genreId]; 
                    // Execute final query and upload
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (url,title,genre) VALUES (:url,:title,:genre)";
                    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $q->execute(array(':url'=>$url,
                                      ':title'=>$title,
                                      ':genre'=>$genre));       
                    if(copy($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],'../images/'.$newFileName)) {
                        $NOTICE = 'File successfully uploaded!';
                        // I AM NEVER REACHING THIS NOTICE WHICH IS ECHOED LATER ON IN THE CODE
                    }
                }else{
                    $NOTICE = "Please fill out the title for picture ".$i;
                    break;                  
                }
            }
    }else{
        $NOTICE = "Please select a file to upload in slot ".$i;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: What makes you "believe you experience an error"? I'd suggest you post some more code here, what I can see now could probably work.

Comment: Why don't you try it first, the ask the question

Comment: I added the whole loop... I am having issues in general with it, all the data IS being uploaded to the MySQL database but the file IS NEVER reaching the destination folder

@Eritrea ... I did try it first and tried to fix it. My main question was can I but variables in the [] like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(copy($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],'../images/'.$newFileName)) {
```

I believe should be:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],'../images/'.$newFileName)) {
```

And yes, you can put variables in [] like that. So long as they're valid and won't result in an undefined offset error.

Comment: I tried this but it is still not working... There may be something messed up with my directory listing? I have the folder `images` in my public_html directory but this script is in `admin/upload.php` but using the `../` it should be going back to the public_html directory and then the images directory? Correct? It used to work but I added in the loop to do multi-file upload and only this part got screwed up...

Comment: Not necessarily. I use absolute paths when I handle files: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mysite/media/images/".$newFileName - obviously replacing the path with your actual path... Dumb question, but are you sure your form has the enctype="multipart/form-data" param set?

Comment: No, you're trying to help so it's not a dumb question and yes I do. It used to work yesterday but I wanted to make it more dynamic, not one file at a time so I made it so you could do 20 at once... And I will use the root and see if that produces any positive results.

Comment: I just tried that and even "echo'ed" out the the server root with the images/file concatenated onto it and it was exact but the file does not exist, the folder is still empty.

Comment: `$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/'.$newFileName;
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], $directory)) {

      $NOTICE = 'File successfully uploaded!';

     }`

Comment: I apologize for wasting everyones time! One simple stupid error on my part is should be `$_FILES[$fileField]` NOT `$_FILES['fileField']` You gave me help in narrowing it down and made my code better and safer and were of the most assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `copy`. Use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) first, before you do anything with the uploaded file. Files are uploaded to a special, temporary location.

Comment: I tried this but it is still not working... There may be something messed up with my directory listing? I have the folder `images` in my public_html directory but this script is in `admin/upload.php` but using the `../` it should be going back to the public_html directory and then the images directory? Correct? It used to work but I added in the loop to do multi-file upload and only this part got screwed up...